# C# Joystick Input

Tags: c#, input, usb, device, joystick

I've got a Logitech Attack 3 (Standard Joystick) plugged into my computer and have confirmed that it is working. Now given that, I need a way via C# (only C#) to read the axis (and buttons would be nice too) values from the joystick. I have seen many examples which use DirectX, but are from 8 years ago and no longer work with .NET 4.5...Hence, I need a .NET 4.5 solution that works on Visual Studio 2012. I have done extensive research on this and cannot find a way to get simple coordinates from a joystick. Any help would  be appreciated. Thanks!

I have tried to use SlimDx, but have no idea what code to write.
Also, this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/joystick.aspx <-- this is from 2006, and no longer works with .NET 4.5 for some reason.

Comment: Have you looked at http://shahardev.blogspot.in/2011/10/talking-to-joysticks-using-slimdx.html and http://slimdx.org/docs/html/T_SlimDX_DirectInput_Joystick.htm ?

Comment: would just like to state that the first link in @AmitMittal 's comment is practically useless as they code samples don't show up anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those examples you've looked at should still be fairly correct. What has changed is the directX version and I think you should have a look at directX11 to use in your project.